# VLCSharp Unity3D, video Streaming freezes but audio still working

Tags: windows, unity-game-engine, streaming, rtmp, libvlcsharp

I want to get a RTMP link and stream the video at my unity project but, and it works fine.... just 4 frames long cause after that it freezes, but audio stills playing.

For this code i´m using VSCode,Unity3D and the public example that the creators have on their [github](https://code.videolan.org/videolan/vlc-unity/-/blob/master/Assets/VLCUnity/Demos/Scripts/MinimalPlayback.cs).

```
 // This is the start, where i initialize things of course hahauhsuhs
void Start()
{
    Core.Initialize(Application.dataPath);

    _libVLC = new LibVLC();
    PlayPause();
}


 //Then here we have the method play and Pause, where we play Media Player and give him the media URL that works for a few frames.

 private void PlayPause()
{
    if (_mediaPlayer == null)
    {
        _mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(_libVLC);
    }
    if (_mediaPlayer.IsPlaying)
    {
        _mediaPlayer.Pause();
    }
    else
    {
        _isPlaying = true;

        if (_mediaPlayer.Media == null)
        {
            // playing remote media
            _mediaPlayer.Media = new Media(_libVLC, new Uri(URL));
        }

        _mediaPlayer.Play();

    }
}

// This method will be execute every frame and do some crazy stuff that i can´t explane right now.

private void Update()
{
    //A few checks before executing video
    if (!_isPlaying) return;

    if (URL.Equals(null)) URL = "http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"; //if URL is null give the BigChungus Bunny video

    //Execute Video
    if (_tex == null)
    {
        // If received size is not null, it and scale the texture
        uint i_videoHeight = 0;
        uint i_videoWidth = 0;

        _mediaPlayer.Size(0, ref i_videoWidth, ref i_videoHeight);
        var texptr = _mediaPlayer.GetTexture(out bool updated);

        if (i_videoWidth != 0 && i_videoHeight != 0 && updated && texptr != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            Debug.Log("Creating texture with height " + i_videoHeight + " and width " + i_videoWidth);
            _tex = Texture2D.CreateExternalTexture((int)i_videoWidth,
                (int)i_videoHeight,
                TextureFormat.RGBA32,
                false,
                true,
                texptr);

            RenderSettings.skybox.mainTexture = _tex;
        }
    }
    else if (_tex != null)
    {
        var texptr = _mediaPlayer.GetTexture(out bool updated);
        if (updated)
        {
            _tex.UpdateExternalTexture(texptr);
        }
    }
    
}
```

this is my first real question on stackover flow so this post can have some issues, I´m open for suggestion to improve it.

Comment: share full logs

Answer (score 0):

I found that the problem it´s with my stream server latency, and not with my unity project.
But still... there is a way to persist the video to play with high latency?